# Was (genau) ist trennbar und wie soll es (englisch) heißen?

Tags: verb, separable-verb

Beim Verb „anerkennen“ ist höchstens der Teil „an“ abtrennbar bzw. separable. Das Wort „anerkennen“ als „trennbares Verb“ (englisch: *separable verb*) zu bezeichnen ist also nicht besonders sinnvoll bzw. hilfreich. Als Verb ist es vielleicht trennbar, man muss bloß wissen, wo die Trennstelle liegt.

Der Begriff „trennbar“ ist an sich eigentlich unproblematisch: „an“ ist separable bzw. abtrennbar. Aber was ist eigentlich dieses „an“? Leider entspricht kein englisches Wort dem Wort „Vorsilbe“ und das englische Wort *„prefix“* braucht man für Präfixverben. Vorschläge oder Bemerkungen zur deutschen Terminologie wären willkommen.

Comment: Please decide: Do you want to write your question in German or in English. You started in German, then switched to English and in the last parenthesis back to German again. **Please edit you question** and ask what you want to ask in only **one** language. If you decide to ask in English, you still can use German terms for grammatical entities. This can make sense, because some of these entities (and therefore also their names) might not exist in English grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Abtrennbare Verbteile heißen "Partikel" oder "Verbzusatz". Die Redeweise "trennbares Präfix" wird zum Glück allmählich zurückgedrängt. Der betonte Teil in "ANerkennen" ist abtrennbar, das ist ganz regelmäßig, nur der Rest "er-kennen" hat halt noch ein Präfix. In der Perfektform "AB-ge-trennt" ist es eigentlich nicht anders.

"particle verb" a term that is also used in English.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikelverb

Comment: Danke. Der Artikel bei Wikipedia ist interessant: was hin und her wandert, ist also nicht die Partikel sonden das Verb; und der Begriff 'Zusammenrückung' ist mir neu. Leider versteht sich 'particle' im Englischen meistens nur im engeren Sinn, wenn überhaupt.

Answer (score 0):

Das deutsche Verb *»trennen«* hat mehrere Bedeutungen, die zu unterschiedlichen englischen Übersetzungen führen. Die Bedeutung, um die es hier geht (nämlich das Teilen eines trennbaren Verbs in zwei separate Wörter), wird üblicherweise als *»to separate«* übersetzt. Verben, die man in bestimmten grammatischen Umgebungen trennen muss, während sie in anderen zusammengesetzt bleiben, nennt man daher im Deutschen *»trennbare Verben«* und auf English *»separable verbs«.*

Der lateinische Name für Silbe ist *»fix«.* (Eigentlich ist das eine Verkürzung des lateinische Wortes *»fixum«* welches *»das Angefügte«*  bedeutet, aber ich will da nicht zu sehr ins Detail gehen.)
Die Vorsilbe *»vor-«* ist lateinisch *»pre-«,* die Vorsilbe *»zwischen-«* ist *»inter-«* und die deutsche Vorsilbe *»nach-«* kann im Lateinischen als *»post-«* oder *»suf-«* übersetzt werden. Daraus ergeben sich diese lateinischen Bezeichnungen:

| Deutsch | Latein |
| --- | --- |
| Vorsilbe | prefix |
| Zwischensilbe | interfix |
| Nachsilbe | postfix, suffix |

Die englische Sprache hat selbst keine eigenen Begriffe für diese Wortbestandteile und verwendet daher die lateinischen Begriffe. Man findet die lateinischen Namen auch in deutschen Texten, dann werden diese Wörter aber mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben geschrieben, weil es Substantive sind, und die lateinische Vorsilbe »pre-« wird zu »prä-« verdeutscht: *Präfix, Interfix, Postfix, Suffix.*

Das, was bei einem trennbaren Verb abgespalten werden kann, ist eine Silbe (Silbe = engl. *syllable*), und sie befindet sich am Beginn des Wortes, steht also *vor* dem Rest des Wortes, und daher ist das eine *Vorsilbe* bzw. ein *Präfix* und die englische Bezeichnung dafür ist: *prefix.*

Allerdings steht dieser Teil, sobald er abgespalten ist, nicht mehr am Anfang des Wortes, daher ist der abgetrennte Teil dann auch keine Vorsilbe mehr. Die Bezeichnung *Präfix* (engl. *prefix*) ist dann irreführend und eigentlich sogar falsch. Trotzdem wird dieser Teil in manchen Lehrbüchern auch dann als *Präfix* (*prefix*) bezeichnet, wenn er weit weg von seinem Verb am Ende des Satzes steht.

Daher wird in moderneren Lehrbüchern stattdessen der Begriff *»Partikel«* verwendet. Dieses Wort kommt aus der lateinischen Sprache. Die deutsche Übersetzung lautet eigentlich *»Teilchen«,* wird in der Grammatik aber nie verwendet. Der englische Ausdruck ist: *particle.* Eine Partikel ist in der Grammatik ein Wort, das niemals gebeugt oder dekliniert wird und das keine  Präposition, kein Adverb und keine Konjunktion ist. Die Partikeln werden wiederum in mehrere Unterklassen unterteilt, und jene Partikel, die in anderen grammatischen Umgebungen Vorsilben von trennbaren Verben sind, nennt mal *»Verbal-Partikel«* (engl: *verbal particles*). Das bedeutet nichts anders, als dass es Partikeln sind, die zu Verben gehören. Manchmal findet man auch den Begriff *»Präverb«* (engl. *preverb*), allerdings wird dieser Begriff z.B. auch in der englischen Grammatik verwendet. Damit werden z.B die Wörter *»on«, »off«, »in«* und *»out«* in den Verben *»to put on«, »to put off«, »to put in«* und *»to put out«* bezeichnet, die grammatisch sehr ähnlich funktionieren wie die deutschen trennbaren Vorsilben, jedoch mit dem wichtigen Unterschied, dass im Englischen diese Teile niemals zusammengeschrieben werden.

Auf Englisch wird manchmal auch von *»separable verb prefixes«* (deutsch: *abtrennbare Verbvorsilben*) gesprochen.

Beispiele:

- trennbares Verb nicht getrennt:

  > Wir werden deinen Erfolg **anerkennen.**

  - **an-**
    In dieser Konstellation ist die Silbe *»an-«* eine Vorsilbe (engl. *prefix*)
  - **-erkennen**
    Das ist der Hauptteil des Verbs. Ich habe leider keine gängige Bezeichnung dafür gefunden.
- trennbares Verb getrennt:

  > Wir **erkennen** deinen Erfolg **an.**

  - **an**
    In dieser Konstellation ist der Teil *»an«* keine Vorsilbe eines anderen Wortes, sondern ein eigenes Wort. Es ist eine Verbalpartikel.
  - **erkennen**
    In dieser Konstellation erscheint das Verb wie ein ganz gewöhnliches Verb.

Beachte, dass das Wort *»an«* im letzten Beispiel eine Verbalpartikel ist, die wieder zu einer Vorsilbe werden kann, wenn man am Satz etwas verändert. Das Wort *»an«* kann aber auch ohne Verb verwendet werden:

- Präposition:

  > Der Besen lehnt **an** der Wand.
- Adverb:

  > Bitte mach das Licht **an.**

Die Verbalpartikel *»an«*, die Präposition *»an«* und das Adverb *»an«* sind streng genommen drei verschiedene Wörter. Es sind Homonyme. Aber natürlich sind sie sehr eng miteinander verwandt.

---

Viele deutsche Verben haben aber auch Vorsilben, die man nicht abtrennen kann:

> Ich werden dich **erkennen.**
> Ich **erkenne** dich. (nicht: <del>Ich kenne dich er.</del>)

Das Verb *»kennen«* existiert zwar auch als eigenes Verb in der deutschen Sprache (*»Ich kenne dich«*), und daher ist es auch korrekt, die Silbe *»er-«* als Vorsilbe (engl. *prefix*) zu bezeichnen, aber es ist keine abtrennbare Vorsilbe und kann daher niemals zu einer Verbalpartikel werden.

Comment: Vielen Dank für den Vortrag (und für die Korrekturen an meiner revidierten Frage), aber das alles verstehe ich schon. Es liegt mir vielmehr daran, diese Partikeln (im allerweitesten Sinn) als erkennbare Wortgruppe zu definieren, um sie dann von einem anderen Standpunkt aus zu untersuchen, und dazu wäre eine passende und sinnvolle englische Bezeichnung hilfreich.

Comment: Man sollte hier nicht mit der Bezeichnung "Silbe" operieren... Affix und Silbe gehören in zwei verschiedene Gebiete. Die "Vorsilbe" *zusammen-* wäre dann "eine Vorsilbe, die aus 3 Silben besteht"... da verheddert man sich ja. Das Interfix *-s* in Komposita ist absolut keine Silbe.  Ich weiß, traditionell wurden Morpheme auch Silben genannt, aber man sollte das nicht weiterschleppen. -- Mir ist aber noch nie aufgefallen, dass die Bezeichnung "Partikel" außerdem den Vorzug hat, dass sie bei Distanzstellung genauso gut passt, guter Punkt.

Comment: Ja, Silben sind in diesem Zusammenhang problematisch. Wenn wir uns nur alle auf die Bezeichnung 'Partikel' einigen koennten!